# How to recovery LAMP?

Tags: apache2, data-recovery, lamp

I installed LAMP but then I had to erase some package(apache2, mysql-server) and load them. But more than one problem occurred. So  I want to delete all the packages and installed them again.I said to use the synaptic package manager, but it's hard to pick individual packages.

What can I do ?

Comment: How did you originally install LAMP?  And why won't that work again?

Comment: I did not install it in one package. Apache Mysql PHP.